# relocate C:\Users\USERNAME to an encrypted partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, encryption, veracrypt

Forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question or missing an obvious solution or a simpler alternative.  Let me lay out first what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have one machine running Windows 7 Home installed to a system partition, and two separate user profiles (**User1** and **User2**).  What I'd like to do is to migrate all user libraries (ex. **C:\Users\User1** and **C:\Users\User2**) to two separate Veracrypt encrypted partitions (ex. **X:\User1** and **Z:\User2**).

What I've tried so far is [changing the ProfileImagePath registry entry to point to the new location](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87555-user-profile-change-default-location.html) which resulted in Windows launching a temporary profile at login (basically as though a new user profile had just been logged in).

In addition to that, I tried changing individual registry entries at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellFolders to point to the new locations, which results in the desktop not being able to load and windows throwing errors because it cannot access the encrypted drive.

The only other thing I can think to do is to toss out the idea of encryption and just remove permissions to access the partition from the opposite user, but that doesn't provide any real privacy protection for the non-administrator account.  Is there a workaround or a method that I'm not savvy enough to see?  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: At what point are those partitions unlocked? They'd need to be accessible before user login.

Comment: @Seth The partitions are unlocked at login.  Very new to veracrypt, so I'm not entirely sure there's any way to unlock *before* login.